# Accessing environment variables from Cypress Fixture

Tags: javascript, api, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, cypress

I have just started using Cypress for API test automation. There are some environment variables I'll like to access in my test files using `Cypress.env`. The cypress documentation lists the config file (`cypress.json`) as the obvious place to store environment variables.

I need to test numerous endpoints from over 40 data services companies. The business logic varies across all 40 services.

Hence, the objects in the `"env"` within `cypress.json` are numerous, so not manageable within one file.

My thought process to resolving this, is to create an environment variable file within Fixtures, storing the `"env"` objects for each of the data services. However I'm not sure if that's possible.

Also, is it possible to have more than one `cypress.json` file in one project?

Any advice will be most appreciated.

Here's a sample of my `"env"` variable for one data service provider.

```
{
    "env": {
        "dataService": "XXDataService",
        "companyRegNo": "XX4457ZZ",
        "language": "EN",
        "countryCode": "UK",
        "companyType": "Ltd",
        "companySearchName": "",
        "searchParams": "",
        "reportParams": "",
        "username": "",
        "password": "",
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `is it possible to have more than one cypress.json file in one project`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have met the same problem and finally make my own plugin.

[cypress-template-fixtures](https://github.com/xpol/cypress-template-fixtures)

Usage

1. `npm i -D cypress-template-fixtures`
2. Add `require('cypress-template-fixtures')(on, config);` in the `cypress/plugins/index.js`.

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('cypress-template-fixtures')(on, config); // Add this line
  return config;
};
```

3. Add the generated fixture folder `cypress/fixtures.out/` into `.gitignore`.
4. Use `{{VAR_NAME}}` in normal fixtures files in `cypress/fixtures` directory.

`cypress/fixtures/example.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "{{NAME}}",
  "title": "{{TITLE}}",
  "email": "{{EMAIL}}",
  "body": "{{BODY}}"
}
```

5. Provide `VAR_NAME` in `cypress.json` or `cypress.env.json`.
6. Or provide `CYPRESS_VAR_NAME` in system or [cypress-dotenv](https://github.com/morficus/cypress-dotenv).

[Read more docs here](https://github.com/xpol/cypress-template-fixtures).

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Option-2-cypress-env-json](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Option-2-cypress-env-json)

> You can create your own `cypress.env.json` file that Cypress will
>   automatically check. Values in here will overwrite conflicting
>   environment variables in your configuration file (`cypress.json` by
>   default).

Comment: Thanks Sree.Bh, can we talk please? 

May be connect via WhatsApp or zoom call?

Comment: @Olubaba: You can add comment here.

Comment: As far as I understand this does not allow you to use environment variables in fixtures still.